# GLFW VBO in World Space

Tags: coordinates, vbo, glfw

Last year I wrote a basic 3D game for one of my modules using freeglut. Everything was fine and dandy because I used the deprecated immediate-mode of drawing things (glBegin, glVertex, glEnd) for drawing all my geometry, and it was fine; everything was positioned where I expected it to be.

This time around, I'd like to use GLFW and Vertex Buffers to create my geometry, since this is what is being used now, as well as increase the performance of my application.

I've read and looked at many tutorials, but I don't understand how I can define the vertex position in world coordinates, as opposed to screen coordinates (-1 to 1).

If someone could provide a basic sample code of how this small feat is achieved, I would be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you've misunderstood how VBOs work (or else read a really really bad tutorial).  You can put your position data in a VBO in any co-ordinate space you like.  There's nothing about a VBO that prevents you from doing this.

Comment: My apologies, perhaps I've phrased this wrongly. While I know I can put any float value I want in the vertex buffer, on the screen I can only see between -1 and 1. How can I change my viewing mode to pixel coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for seems to be how to setup a synthetic camera. Objects can be placed in the world in arbitrary positions, however in order to actually see them you need to have a camera appropriately positioned.

**How to setup the camera?**

By asking this question I assume you don't know how synthetic cameras work. You should be familiarized with the Model, View and Projection matrices and how they relate. For a good tutorial, I recommend http://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Camera.

**How to setup the camera in modern pipeline?**

Assuming you know what Model, View and Projection matrices are, you probably know by now that these were embedded within the fixed pipeline. However, nowadays we must calculate them ourselves, and one of the most used libraries to do that is the GLM (OpenGL Mathematics library).

To calculate them, we use glm::lookAt for the view and glm::projection for the projection matrix. Calculating these matrices, and assuming you have a model matrix (you can set it to identity for now), you should multiply them in this order: projection * view * model. The ModelViewProjection matrix must be sent to your shader and each object vertex should be multiplied by it.

**Example**

I have a very basic Plane demo scenario that you can use. First, set the matrices.

```
modelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(
    vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), //eye
    vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), //center
    vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)); //up
projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(glm::radians(60.0f), 1.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
modelViewMatrix = viewMatrix * modelMatrix;
modelViewProjectionMatrix = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix;
```

Now you must send the MVP matrix to the respective shader using the appropriate opengl functions (glUniform*) and multiply the MVP matrix for each vertex within the vertex shader.

```
gl_Position = MVP * vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0);
```

Now, let's position an object. We know the camera is looking towards +z and positioned at (0,0,-1). So if we place a 1x1 plane at (0,0,2) you should be able to see it perfectly.

I have a couple of very simple demos showing that.You can check out here: https://github.com/tiiago11/cga-demos/blob/master/demos/glsl40_plane/src/Plane.cpp

Hope it helps.